# Condição If no where SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, data, filtro

Tenho uma `Stored Procedure` onde preciso fazer uma verificação para um filtro de datas, caso a data inicial seja nula tenho que fazer no `WHERE` pegar todos os registros menor que a data final, senão faço um `BETWEEN` entre as datas.

### Exemplo

Se a data inicial for nula faço:

```
select * from tabela where campoTabela <= @datafim
```

Senão:

```
select * from tabela where data between @dataInicial and @datafim
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma e a performance ficou muito ruim, a consulta toda é uma select  com 3 sub-selects 3 utilizando union all eu faço a verificação da variavel fora do primeiro select caso seja nulo executo a consulta utilizando <= datafim senão faço com o between. Fiz uma consulta só utilizando o primeiro critério e são retornados 30 registros, quando apliquei o segundo já passou uma hora de execução e não retornou nada.

Comment: (**1**) Como está declarada a coluna `data`? (**2**) A tabela possui índice pela coluna `data`?

Answer (score 3):

Como é um procedimento armazenado é preciso ficar atento para evitar *parameter sniffing*, assunto explicado de forma didática no artigo [Introdução ao parameter sniffing no SQL Server](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/09/03/introducao-parameter-sniffing/).

Caso exista índice pela coluna `data`, eis sugestão:

```
-- código #1
-- gera variáveis internas de limite
declare @xDataInicial date, @xDataFinal date;

IF @datainicial is not null
  set @xDataInicial= @datainicial
else
  set @xDataInicial= (SELECT top (1) data from tabela order by data);
set @xDataFinal= @datafim;

--
SELECT colunas
  from tabela
  where data between @xDataInicial and @xDataFinal;
```

No código acima as variáveis @xDataInicial e @xDataFinal devem ser declaradas do mesmo tipo de dados da coluna `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer assim:

```
if (@dataInicial is null)
begin

    select * from tabela where campoTabela <= @datafim

end
else
begin

    select * from tabela where data between @dataInicial and @datafim

end
```

Verificas se o parâmetro é nulo e de acordo com isso faz o seu select!

Abaixo segue demonstração.. quando for `null` o texto exibido é NULO, e quando não for é exibido NÃO NULO.

**NÃO NULO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**NULO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se o objetivo for executar tudo em apenas uma consulta, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tabela 
WHERE   (@dataInicial IS NULL       AND campoTabela <= @datafim)
    OR  (@dataInicial IS NOT NULL   AND data BETWEEN @dataInicial AND @datafim)
```

Ao colocar o `OR` consegue ter as duas condições na cláusula `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso como segue

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE (Data >= @dataInicial AND Data <= @datafim) 
       OR 
      (@dataInicial IS NULL AND Data <= @datafim);
```